# How to hide members of groups from other members within same group

Tags: 2007, permissions, wss-3.0, groups

I have not been able to  find a way to make this possible yet, but we don't want any members to be able to see who else is in their permission groups.

I've seen the setting for limiting membership visibility to individual groups, but we want it even more restricted, where if you're a member of Group A, you won't even be able to tell who else is in Group A.

We're using WSS 3.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You get the following security options when creating a group in SharePoint:

*Who can view the membership of the group?*

- Group Member
- Everyone

*Who can edit the membership of the group?*

- Group Owner
- Group Members

To me, it doesn't sound like these options would fit your requirements.

I'd say you need some custom coding. This is how I would implement it:

Code something that will disallow access to people.aspx for, let's say, non Site Collection Administrators. Create a custom WebControl and put it on the page by adding it through a DelegateControl Feature (AdditionalPageHead). On Page Load, This control should perform the security check and redirect to AccessDenied page when user is on the people.aspx page and the current user is not a Site Collection Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

a heavy handed approach might be to use AD groups

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by Jaap has some merit. The problem is that when accessing documents through any Office application users will still be able to use the document workspace, which exposes the users.

The heavy handed approach here would be to [disable the Document Workspace Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/souravd/archive/2009/06/03/disable-shared-workspace-for-all-users-when-opening-office-2003-and-2007-files-from-sharepoint-document-library.aspx) (dws.asmx) on the server.Unfortunatley this would effect all sites on your server, so if you are trying to achieve this for a specific site it will not be suitable.