# How to hide permission group membership list from members

Tags: permissions, office-365, groups, extranet

This has been asked before and sort of answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/2543/49640) with a workaround.

However I'm hoping that there is a more direct solution.

I need to use permission groups to restrict access to content for an extranet portal. I don't want group members to see who else is in the group - it's commercially-sensitive information.

The only options for 'Who can view the membership of the group?' are 'members' or 'everyone'. I need an extra option: 'owner' (which is available for 'edit group membership' - I'm slightly confused why this isn't also an option out of the box for 'view membership'...)

If anyone knows how to implement this across a site collection please let me know.

Alternatively if anyone has successfully implemented the linked workaround I'd be keen to see the code.

We're on SharePoint 2013 (hosted) in Office 365.

Thanks

-E

Comment: Are you looking for a no code solution or C#/CSOM/JSOM/Powershell based solution?

Comment: I really don't mind, as long as it's robust. We're on SPO so I need something that can be easily reactivated if an update wipes out some of the configuration. Or even better, something that will persist through updates.

I have a custom master page, because it appears to be the only way to edit the menus, but I'd rather keep the changes in there to a minimum so I can reapply them if they get randomly wiped out.

Comment: Note that if the group only has Read or Contribute permissions to the site (or to specific content), members of that group won't have access to **Site Settings**, so they won't have a navigable path to the group page exposed within the UI.  If you don't send the welcome email when adding them, the only remaining way for them to reach the group page in the first place is if they manually type the URL `sitepath/_layouts/15/groups.aspx` and then find the group in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I am using OnPrem, so I don't know if this will work for 365, but I use an AD group inside the SharePoint group.  It will not list the users by name.

Additionally, and I hate myself for suggesting this, but if you add them directly to the site by name and not in a group, they can't see the permissions page unless they have full control.

Finally, unless you use an AD group to hide the list of names, anyone can look at the list http://yoursite.com/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0 and see who is on the site.  :-(